# Vue js image v-bind src not working because of incorrect path when receiving the dynamic value from an API call wiht axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having a problem displaying images whose paths I want to get from an SQL database that I have then display them on my website project. This is the way in which I'm trying to make it work:

```
<div class="imagesInQuestion">
  <img class="inlineImages" :src="testItem.pictureLink" />
</div>
```

And in `testItem.pictureLink` I have this string `"@/assets/b1q2v1.png"`

This doesn't work because the path of the image changes. In the network tab of developer options the Request URL changes to

***localhost:8080/courses/tests/@/assets/b1q2v1.png***

Then when I input the string manually without v-bind:

```
<div class="imagesInQuestion">
  <img class="inlineImages" src="@/assets/b1q2v1.png" />
</div>
```

The picture gets displayed with a request URL of

***localhost:8080/img/b1q2v1.2aa65ed1.png***

I have tried solutions like

```
<div class="imagesInQuestion">
  <img
    class="inlineImages"
    :src="required(testItem.pictureLink)"
  />
</div>
```

but it doesn't work, the error is:

> Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/b1q2v1.png'

How do I correctly bind the src attribute to my dynamic picture path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `pictureLink` to just a name:

```
testItem.pictureLink = 'b1q2v1'
```

then create method for getting images:

```
methods: {
  getImage(img) {
    return require(`@/assets/${img}.png`);
  }
}
```

and call that method from template:

```
<img class="inlineImages" :src="getImage(testItem.pictureLink)" />
```

Comment: Hello @Nikola Pavicevic, this solves my problem, thank you very much!!!